# Txt imported table empty rows deletion

Tags: excel

I have a txt imported table (few columns, roughly 3k rows) however it has some empty rows (entirely). I want, with use of formula only, to create a copy of this table without those empty rows. It this possible? If it is, how?

Comment: If what you need is a ONE-TIME action, you can simple SORT your rows. That will pack together the empty rows which you can easily delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013689/1544886 may help, provided of course you change the `"yes"` to `""` and adjust for the number of columns.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7="",ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)),ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1)),"")
```